# Exception message: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

We have Dot.net web application windows server 2016, we have binded the url on IIS v10.
If we browse the url from web its working fine, but whenever we test it from Dynatrace Client we see error.

```
Exception message: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

here is what we se on event.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 3/12/2018 6:00:06 AM 
Event time (UTC): 3/12/2018 10:00:06 AM 
Event ID: 968692c222434a6396144999bc967aef 
Event sequence: 566 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-xxxxx
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\path\path 
    Machine name: server 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6916 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: server\tappp

Exception information: 
    Exception type: UriFormatException 
    Exception message: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://server.app.local:1110/ccccll.svc 
    Request path: /ccccll.svc 
    User host address: xx.xxx.xx.xx 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: server\app 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 80 
    Thread account name: server\app 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```